# Documentation for bibliography management is confusing

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing

In the [wikibooks page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management) for bibliography management, a table is presented under the section BibTeX with the following legend:

- + for required fields
- o for optional fields

However, in the table itself additional symbols appear including:

- an asterisk *
- an asterisk followed by a number

This adds to the confusion of what is already a confusing topic.

What does these additional symbols mean, and why are they there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `@book` can have authors and/or editors, so at least one of those fields should have a value. Similarly, for `@inbook` one has to specify the pages for such a record or the chapter number.

Comment: Thanks. I wish they would mention these sorts of details in the docs themselves...